# Can't set breakpoint within class initialization

Tags: python, yaml

I am using a custom YAML tag to define secrets in configuration. The path of the configuration key determines the path of the secret in the key store.

```
import yaml
import pdb

yaml_str="""
databases:
  master:
    user: 'admin'
    pass: !KMS
"""


class KMSSecret(yaml.YAMLObject):

    def __repr__(self):
        pdb.set_trace()

        secret_path = '/' + '/'.join(self._find_key(config))
        return secret_path

    def _find_key(self, data):
        pdb.set_trace()

        for key, value in data.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict) or isinstance(value, list):
                path_item = self._find_key(value)
                if path_item:
                    return [key] + path_item
            elif value is self:
                return [key]

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(self, loader, node):
        return KMSSecret()


yaml.add_constructor(u'!KMS', KMSSecret.from_yaml)
config = yaml.load(yaml_str)
```

Setting a breakpoint within the `__repr__` or `_find_key` has no effect.

The code must be executed at some point since inspecting the `config` variable after loading shows the expected representations.

When adding `print(config)` to the end of the above snippet, the breakpoints work.

I'd like to understand more about what is happening and what I should read up on.

Comment: I'm not familiar about `_find_key`, but `__repr__` is just a function to give you some readable output. So this function won't be called until you want to get some string-like output from this object.

Comment: So, when I inspect the variables while execution is paused, it runs the `__repr__` in the background or in a different process?

Comment: Where do you pause execution? It runs the `__repr__` when you run `print`.

Comment: Using a debugger. Like in PyCharm or pdb. If I understand correctly: If I don't refer to `config` anywhere (`__repr__` not being called) the breakpoints won't have effect. But I can still see the result when setting a breakpoint at the end of the snippet. (i.e. replace `print(config)` with `pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: I am confused about what you said... `__repr__` is a function to give you **readable** output, **readable**. You can surely refer to `config` but it won't trigger `__repr__`. You need `print` or something else such as `repr` to trigger `__repr__`.

Comment: Thank you @Sraw. If it doesn't trigger `__repr__`, how is the value returned by it produced? i.e. (add `pdb.set_trace()` after the above snippet. then type `config` in the pdb console)

Comment: If you try to dive in `pdb`'s source code, when you type `config` in interactive shell, it just trigger `repr` function.

Comment: For the record, you should place `yaml_tag = u'!KMS'` inside the class and remove the `add_constructor` call. `add_constructor` is for objects *not* derived from `YAMLObject`.